# groovy .execute waitFor hangs in Jenkins, but not CL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sqlplus

Good Day,
I have a groovy script running on a jenkins job like so.

```
//checkoutObjects
def command =""
for (i = 0; i <numOfObj; i++) {
command = "svn export -r "+DeploySetArray[i][1]+" "+DeploySetArray[i][0]+" D:/Jenkins/workspace/mmb.database.deploy"
//println command.execute().text
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

println "Process exit code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
println "Std Err: ${proc.err.text}"
println "Std Out: ${proc.in.text}" 
}
```

The above snippet works great, checks out all my SVN objects. Now the below part is where I have the issue.

```
command = "sqlplus mastermind/***@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=***))) @D:/BuildScripts/MMB/gather_invalids.sql"

def proc = command.execute()
println "This line is printed"
proc.waitFor()      
println "This line is not printed"        
println "Process exit code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
println "Std Err: ${proc.err.text}"
println "Std Out: ${proc.in.text}"
```

For some reason when trying to run this groovy script through Jenkins, or running directly from groovy console It waits on this line. However if i extract the sqlplus command exactly and run that by itself on CL it returns within a few seconds. I've looked up a few answers that I thought were close, but it seems weird that it works fine on command line but not through groovy. Any advice or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT: I've tried using another command line tool "sql" instead of "sqlplus". Script is still hanging in the same spot, making me think its something to do with groovy

Comment: have you tried passing the command as an Array instead of String..?

Comment: I like the suggestion, I just tried that and it still seems to hang in the same place. i used "command = command.split()" before the execute to do this

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, my issue wasn't groovy related though. The problem was with the commandline tools 'sql', and 'sqlplus'. When these programs are called with a script to execute, they will run the script and then without exiting prompt for more interaction. This caused the script to hang while it was waiting for more input. I got around this by preceeding my command with "exit | sqlplus..."
This link is what helped me. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/87035/run-oracle-sql-script-and-exit-from-sqlplus-exe-via-command-prompt